# Firestore how to do multiple `OR` queries combined with `AND` logic?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I`m developing a react e-commerce app with firestore database where a customer should be able to filter multiple colors (with OR logic) AND multiple styles (with OR logic) AND multiple brands (with OR logic) etc. and retrieve first 50 products matching these filters.

The main constraint here is that although chaining multiple equalities by using .where("category", "==", "T-Shirts").where("color", "==", "Red") is possible, firestore queries (client or server) does allow only single "in" type of queries. That means if a user wants to see black or red products of A and B brands a query like .where('color', 'in', ['Red', 'Black']).where('brand', 'in', ['A', 'B']) is not possible. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations & https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_2 for more details.

What is the best way to achieve this goal ? Should I make two seperate queries and go through data on client side ?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions - stick with one and update or modify it if other data is available or if it can be refined. Duplicate questions spreads answers out as well and causes duplicate effort in many cases.

Comment: Hi @Jay thanks a lot for your comment, after posting the initial question I thought maybe I should break it down to make it more accessible. You have a solid point there, I`ll just delete this one.